# How to specify fallback location as relative path in mfc

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, sdf

In Visual Studio 2010, I have given Fallback Location as "E:\ABC\xyz\". file is created on the given location. But when I give Fallback Location as relative path "..\xyz\", it does not take the path and file is not created. How to give the path relatively? Do I need to give any double quotes for the path?

Comment: Relative paths are - well - relative. Only you as the developer can know, what this path should be relative to. Since you aren't showing any code, or explaining how it fails, there's nothing we can do to help you, though.

Comment: Wouldn't relative be relative to the calling process folder? Have you checked the error returned?